# ASP.NET MVC project structure with multiple subdomains?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, subdomain, projects-and-solutions, project-structure

I have task to create site that contains some subsites. This subsites will use same database and will have relations. Their domain names should differ. For example, domain is **www.mysite.com**. Subsites are

**www.books.mysite.com**

**www.blog.mysite.com**

**www.sport.mysite.com**

I need a help about a project structure to start this application. Can anyone give me any idea? Can I create some MVC4 projects in one solution? or can I do this with Domain Routing?

Answer (score 1):

This has been answered [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15353430/can-i-use-multiple-sub-domains-in-one-solution), but not in great detail, so I'll collate the relevant points here.

A Visual Studio solution has no actual relation to the deployment of the site; it's just a container for various projects. When you deploy these projects, you can define [bindings](http://blogs.technet.com/b/chrad/archive/2010/01/24/understanding-iis-bindings-websites-virtual-directories-and-lastly-application-pools.aspx) for them in IIS. This is a [relatively straightforward process](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731692(v=ws.10).aspx); if you're doing it the simple way from the UI you'll get something like this:

[image: IIS Site Binding UI]

which lets you define which addresses point to where. During development, you'll need similar bindings in your host file to play the part of these IIS bindings for your local machine.